# Can landlords omit fee structure on a lease?

Tags: residential-lease, texas, real-estate, sublease

A brand-new apartment complex, "professionally" managed by a huge management company, has refused to provide details on how much it'll cost to do [lease reassignment](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/300/is-it-legal-for-landlord-to-prohibit-subleasing), with the rationale being that they've never had to do it yet at this very complex, and thus they'll only know how much they'll be charging for it once someone requests it.  And, no, they can't do a "hypothetical" re-assignment yet, either, claiming that it must be a real request.

Is something like this legal?  Can a corporate landlord withhold such information, and only provide it once an actual need arises, knowing full well that it won't be offered as a complementary service?

Comment: What jurisdiction?  In New York, for example, I am unaware of anything that requires landlords to provide up-front notice of fees they might charge. They are not allowed to "unreasonably" refuse a lease assignment, but whether that allows them to request a fee before agreeing to one, I do not know. I do suspect that "we will only agree if you pay a fee, but we won't disclose the fee until the assignment closes" would be considered unreasonable. I doubt it's unreasonable to refuse to name a price for the hypothetical case, however.

Comment: The jurisdiction where this has happened is Texas, where the landlords seem to be quite fond of these re-assignment fees.